# How to customize google place picker widget UI in iOS GoogleMapSDK

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

As I have Integrated **Google Place Picker UI Widget** to access the map and search places , now I want to **customize UI of Map** which is provided in **PlacePicker Widget UI**?